# Resource leak in MFC SendMessage()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am new to MFC.

How to release resource which is passed as `(WPARAM)` in `SendMessage()`.

Here I using "new" to create for it. Following is the snapshot for same.

```
void Build::BuildCube()
{

    SCtPt *data = new SCtPt;
    data->vm = true;
    int dir = 100;
    MFrame()->SendMessage(WM_MAP_NEW, (WPARAM)data, (LPARAM) dir);
}
```

I want to make sure "data" resource get released of this function.

Thanks...

Comment: What is MFrame, and how does it handle that message? Does it keep a reference to that pointer around somewhere? Assuming not, you can safely delete once it's finished handling that message, which will be after SendMessage returns.

Comment: Additionally if not, it may be easier for you to either create an automatic variable or use shared_ptr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [`SendMessage()` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) is a synchronous API, it sends the message to the other window procedure before returning. When the call to `SendMessage()` returns, then data can be freed/released:

```
void Build::BuildCube()
{
    SCtPt *data = new SCtPt;
    data->vm = true;
    int dir = 100;
    MFrame()->SendMessage(WM_MAP_NEW, (WPARAM)data, (LPARAM)dir);
    delete data;
}
```

Or, better yet, you can avoid allocating the data on the heap altogether. Simply allocate it on the stack and let RAII handle the rest:

```
void Build::BuildCube()
{
    SCtPt data;       // don't use "new", so you won't get a pointer
    data.vm = true;
    int dir = 100;
    MFrame()->SendMessage(WM_MAP_NEW, (WPARAM)data, (LPARAM)dir);
    // no delete necessary!
}
```

Comment: Note that this means that it does not need to be allocated on the heap. Just make it a stack variable.

Comment: Is it OK if I delete it function which handle this message OR If it is synchronize API then I guess it is safe to delete it here.

Comment: In function which handle message to delete is ok, but you need remember do not delete again in BuildCube(), better solution is to delete after SendMessage return, so allocate and deallocate is under centralize control.

Comment: If you delete the data like that, then do as Raymond suggests and stick it on the stack. There's absolutely no point in allocating it.

Comment: what if I use postmessage

Answer (score 5):

Did you consider writing the code like this:

```
void Build::BuildCube()
{
  SCtPt data;
  data.vm = true;
  int dir = 100;
  MFrame()->SendMessage(WM_MAP_NEW, (WPARAM)&data, (LPARAM)dir);
}
```

That way the data sent as WPARAM is still a pointer to your object, but when the application gets out of this method's scope, it will invoke the destructor and perform the cleanup for you.

Comment: Why on earth is this down voted? Given the original question, this is the way to go. No need to allocate for SendMessage unless you intend to store the pointer somewhere for later use.

Comment: This would be my suggestion also. With the small exception of data->vm s/b data.vm, since it isn't a pointer.

Comment: Isn't this code wrong? What if the message handler put pointer address somewhere and try to access it some time later? As the BuildCube() is out of scope in that moment there will be a access violation as data is freed.

Answer (score 0):

We usually do this :

At the point the data is allocated, the comment state **explicitly** where it will be deallocated.

```
void Build::BuildCube()
{

    SCtPt *data = new SCtPt; // Will be deallocated in handler of message WM_MAP_NEW
    data->vm = true;
    int dir = 100;
    MFrame()->SendMessage(WM_MAP_NEW, (WPARAM)data, (LPARAM) dir);
}

LRESULT CMainFrame::OnMapNew(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM )
{
  SCtPt *data = (SCtPt*) wParam;
  // do something with data;

  delete data;
}
```

Comment: Comments are great, but they do little to stop resource leaks. It relies on programmers not making mistakes, and we all know that's unlikely. :-) If you really need one, it is better to just make a copy of the data in the receiving window procedure. Let the caller and the callee maintain separate memory management. It is much easier for code reviews to catch errors that way.

Comment: Agreed!! It's not perfect.